# Export data from postgreSQL in SAS XPORT (xpt) format

Tags: postgresql

Is there a convenient, open-source method to generate a SAS XPORT Transport Format (xpt) file from a postgreSQL database for FDA submission?

I have checked the FDA specifications, available at http://www.fda.gov/downloads/ForIndustry/DataStandards/StudyDataStandards/UCM312964.pdf
These state that 'SAS XPORT transport files can be converted to various other formats using commercially available off the shelf software', but no software packages other than SAS are suggested.

The specifications for an SAS XPORT file are available at http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts140.html

I have checked OpenClinica (which is the EDC software we are using), PGAdmin3 and AM (which can import .xpt files, but I didn't find an export method)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way?  Not that I know of.  I think one way or another it will take some development work.

My recommendation is to do it as follows:

1. Write a user-defined function/stored procedure for pulling the data you need for each section.
2. Write a user-defined function to pull this data from each section and arrange it into an XML file.  The[XML functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-xml.html) are likely to come in handy for this.

Of course you could also put the xml conversion in an arbitrary front-end.  However, in general, you will find that the design above forces you to push everything into set-based logic which is likely to be more powerful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Python, my XPORT module can write xpt files. https://github.com/selik/xport

If you have trouble using it, write me a note and I'll try to help. https://github.com/selik/xport/issues